# webview without scroll bars in android app

Tags: android, webview, android-scrollbar

i am trying to load some web pages in web view of my android app. By default when the page gets loaded i want the web page to be within the device screen size, without any scroll bars making to move either horizontally or vertically.Is this possible. I found a option of adding `view port` in the webpage as follows,

```
<meta name='viewport' content="width=devicewidth"/>
```

Here what is mean by device width, if it refers to the android device width which i am using, then how it will be applicable from all the android devices.

what can i do if the web page is out of my control. Is there any way to add the `view port` in my apps code. How to do this.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using combination of

`yourWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        yourWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`

The page will be loaded completely zoomed out and no scrollbars will be getting in the way (I think).

You can also add

```
yourWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
```

to disable zooming.